# Is node.js ideal for image proxy and manipulation tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, proxy

I have a task where every image can be retrieved from multiple sources on the web. I am using node as a proxy service, so that when an image request is received, node internally hits those 3-4 sources available for the image and returns the first one that responds.

I also want to support image manipulation tasks like, cropping, resizing, rotation etc. For this I used imagemagick. But I understand that image manipulation being a heavy task will block the thread. Even if I put a CDN in front of the node server, it would still crash under a lot of load.

What is the best possible arrangement for such a task. Is there a possible workaround in node? Should I switch all the code to some other technology? Or should I keep the proxying part in node and manipulation part somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Do requests and responses in Node.js while starting separate ImageMagick processes to manipulate the images using [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).  In this way Node.js won't be blocking while ImageMagick manipulates the images.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js should be able to handle it.

And even though Image Processing is a heavy task, you don't have to block the thread to make it work. Have an asynchronous framework to pass the images to imagemagick and let it notify node.js via a callback and then back to the client.

Also, if you are expecting a lot of load, you can have the node.js server running on multiple nodes with nginx as a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't miss Node.js module for images manipulation performance - https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

**Comparation example:**

```
  Found images:
  4198671-green-sea-view.jpg
  Beautiful-Sea-Pier-In-Chile-Hdr-Wide-Desktop-Background-Wallpapers-Beautiful-Sea-Wallpaper-.jpg
  Bluestone-valley-view_-_Virginia_-_ForestWander.jpg
Found modules: canvas.js, gm-imagemagic.js, gm.js, lwip.js
== START ==
canvas.js : 4.001 img/sec; done in 7.498536 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 283Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.48
gm-imagemagic.js : 1.206 img/sec; done in 24.88003 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 456Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.59
gm.js : 1.536 img/sec; done in 19.528429 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 490Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.84
lwip.js : 0.406 img/sec; done in 73.891623 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 157Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.56
== DONE ==
```

In this example you can see, than canvas module is the best, regards to speed of processing of images (~4 imgages per second on author's local computer)
I hope it will help to deside if you want proxy or not.